# Rails application ignores rescue statement when TypeError is called

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My controller logic goes like this.

```
def upload
      if params[:request_file_temp_url].nil?
        return redirect_with_rescue :back, :bad_request, message: "cannot upload file"
      end
      document.file = URI.parse(params[:request_file_temp_url])
      document.save
      ...
      ...
rescue TypeError => e
      return redirect_with_rescue :back, :bad_request, message: e.full_messages.join('/')
end
```

But the rescue statement does not rescue the TypeError that occurs in URI.parse line.

Would the error have been raised somewhere else?

Appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: What error do you see? How do you know its not working?

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure a `TypeError` is raised, try rescuing without the error type and see what kind of exception is raised

Comment: This should be a comment on the question instead.